# Simulate File System in JSON

Tags: javascript, json

I'm trying to imitate a file system in JSON. The purpose is just to detect whether a "file" exists or not. I was thinking of a structure like this:

```
var fs = {
  someName: {
    type: 'directory',
    contents: {
      someNameChild: {
        type: 'directory',
        contents: {
          someChild: {
            type: 'file',
            contents: 'hello world!'
          }
        }
      }
    }
 }
}
```

After seeing this I started wondering if anyone knows of anything to simulate a file system in-memory in JSON. I don't want to have to write all of the createDirectory, createFile, removeDirectory, removeFile, etc. file operatons.  I don't need it to be robust in terms of file storage. I'm more interested in the directory structure operations.

Does anyone know of some code that can do this? I figure someone has already tackled this.

Thanks!

Comment: Emulating a file system structure in a JS object would not be hard. You already have your desired format, can't you just build from there? Also, Stack Overflow is meant for answering concrete questions where the asker has put in some research, not for suggesting libraries.

Comment: This is a better fit for http://programmers.stackexchange.com/ This question is too broad. Stack Overflow is for problems you find while trying to write code

Answer (score 2):

A dictionary already has all you need, explicit `type` fields should not be needed, at least not if the scope is folders and files.

```
{
   folderA : {
       folderNested : {
           someFile : "foo content"
       },

       folderNestedB : {

       },
   }
}
```

You do have to implement directory operations, but they are pretty straightforward. For example, to navigate to a path in the file system you could simply

```
var pieces = path.split('/');

var node = root; 
for (var i = 0; i < pieces.length; ++i) {
    node = node[pieces[i]];
    if (!node) {
       // error, not found
    }
    break;
}

// |node| is the file/folder
```

Comment: I think the point of your answer is that the OP should consider objects to be directories and strings to be files? That would work if you don't need to store permissions. Also, I think the question is how to implement addDirectory, deleteDirectory, addFile, deleteFile